# My Minecraft villagers won't stop throwing food at each other

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Over the past few "Minecraft days" I've spent in the village I built, I noticed all of my villagers are huddled in one house, standing there throwing food at the same villager. They've been doing this for about 3 days straight, and I can't get them to just stop chucking potatoes at each other. Does anyone know how to make them stop??

[image]

Comment: Which version? 1.12.2, 1.13.2, 19w13b or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It seems they are 'willing', and looking for 'willing' partners:

> Any villager with an excess of food (usually farmers) will throw food
> to other villagers, allowing them to pick it up and obtain enough food
> to become willing.

Why they keep going at it (throwing potatoes, that is) might be because their mating conditions are not met:

> Villagers will mate depending on the number of valid doors. If "willing", villagers will
> mate as long as the population is less than 35% (Bedrock Edition:
> 100%) of valid doors, rounded
> down.

Once they have mated, they should lose their incessant interest in flinging food at each other.

<sup>[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding)</sup>

Comment: thank you they have now populated my town lol

Comment: @muffin If this helps you, accept the answer (press the checkmark under the votes ting)